# Как вставить строку в двумерный массив без готовых методов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Задача такая - задана строка в двумерном массиве, мне нужно перед ней вставить строку с нулями, а сам массив сдвинуть на +1. Хотел реализовать на js но тут такое дело, когда я задаю значение каждого из элементов строки на 0, она меняет и элементы следующей строки на 0 также. Все это делаю без использования splice и готовых методов.

```
    //Двумерные массивы, вставка столбика или строки
//4.10.1
//Функция вставки строки с нулями, после заданной строки.
function addRowsZero(whatRow, array, lengthRows, LengthCows){
array.length = lengthRows + 1;
var n = lengthRows;
while (whatRow<n){
array[n] = array[n-1]
n--;
}
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++)
        arr[0][j]=0;
    return array;
}

//создаем и заполняем массив
var  n = 10;
var m = 4; 
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i <n; i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(m);
    for (var j = 0; j<m; j++)
        arr[i][j]=Math.round(Math.random()*100);
}
console.log(arr);
//запускаем функцию 
addRowsZero(0, arr, n, m);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

При переносе вы присваиваете не скалярную переменную, а массив. js в этом случае копирует ссылку, в итоге 0й и 1й элементы массива ссылаются на один и тот же массив. вам надо 0-му элементу присвоить `arr[0]=new Array` и потом спокойно заполнять его нулями.

Comment: Сделал, все работает. Только я немного не понял. Подскажите, что по этому поводу почитать. Когда я писал аналогичный код на с++, почему-то не они ссылались на одно и тоже.

Comment: @VladyslavAlifanov Это смотря как объявить массив в c++, если  в виде `int a[10][10]` выделяется сплошная область памяти и вы наверняка после этого вынуждены копировать каждое значение или просто кусок памяти каким нибудь memcpy. Если вы объявите `int *a[10]`, т.е. массив указателей, потом с помощью new создадите эти подмассивы и будете пытаться сделать точно так как делаете тут  в js то и получите такой же результат. почитать ... в гугле вбейте "js указатели", что нибудь найдете. Просто js для экономии ресурсов всегда себя так ведет, любое не скалярное значение копируется как указатель